# How to release wire from a Eaton Moeller M22-CK10 NO contact block?

Tags: contact

I am attempting to rewire a fan to a [M22-CK10 contact block](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1801040.pdf?_ga=2.238672832.1555000570.1511994495-1848302695.1511994495).

The device is shown below:

[image: contact block]

My first thought was to push in the metal contacts above the red wire on the left.

When that didn't work I tried pushing the contact holding the let red wire.  I experimented with the empty socket on the left but there was no sign of the clamp opening.  There is a green contact button on the rear that doesn't seem to do anything either when I press it.

There doesn't seem to be anything else, I don't want to destroy the contact block and it feels if I force it further I will.

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to release the wire from the contact block?

Comment: http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/CustomerSupport/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

They show how to insert the wire , but not extract.

call aftersales support emergency line.

[image]

Since the strands are folded after insertion, it improves restraint, but makes it harder to remove without leaving in broken strands. Rotating the wire gently in the strand wind direction may allow it to be removed without breaking the wire or junction.